# Idiom for “luckiest person in the world”

Tags: idioms

Could you please provide idioms for “luckiest person in the world”?

I’d appreciate helpful links.

Comment: _(have the) luck of the devil/Irish_

Comment: In what context do you want to use it?  Expressions vary from "*having a Midas touch*" to "*being a regular Mr. Magoo*,"  which while both mean they are very lucky, have very different applications.

Answer (score 1):

He:

***[holds the aces](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hold+all+the+aces)*** or ***all the aces*** or ***all four aces***

Referring to a very rare hand in poker--four aces, it could be interpreted as the luckiest, but it is also commonly interpreted as in control of the situation.

***[gets all the breaks](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+breaks)***

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with "holds all the aces" since the idiom often applies to someone who has their benefits through skill or work on their part rather than luck. "Gets all the breaks" though is spot-on.

Comment: I agree, that "being in control" by way of position is the predominant usage for *holding all the aces*, but "holding aces" was listed as a synonym for lucky. **If** *holding aces* is lucky, then *holding all the aces* is luckiest? http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/lucky?s=t